# Python help lazy loading large data sets

Tags: python, database, bigdata, generator

I have a script which loads data into a database.  I grab data from csv files and return a generator.  The values yielded from the generator are used to build insert statements for bulk loading up to a 100K records at a time.  Currently I have a function that looks like this to build a "list of lists":

```
def split_statements(data_set, num_of_splits):
        return iter([data_list[pos:pos + num_of_splits] for pos in xrange(0, len(data_list), num_of_splits)])
```

This works fine for 1 line up to several million lines of data, splitting the latter into 100K chunks.  However I have been trying to switch to some sort of generator / lazy loading function for edge cases of extremely large files.  I tried the following:

```
def split_statements(data_set, num_of_splits):
    for i in data_set:
        yield list(islice(data_set, num_of_splits))
```

This seems clunky and does not work when there is only 1 line in a file.  However it worked great on a 10GB file.

Would appreciate any insight/help.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure this is a very good fit for Code Review, at least in the way it is worded: _"does not work when there is only 1 line in a file"_ makes it sound like there are problems with the code still before it works as intended, in which cases it would be better left on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Is there any problem with putting the question in both places?

Comment: @Phrancis I agree (c:

Comment: @user982599 it would be better to not post both on Code Review and Stack Overflow, as chances are it would be off-topic on one of the sites or the other. In this case, I see you posted on CR just now and chances are it will be closed there.

Comment: :( sorry - i will delete the question on CR

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it really worked on the 10GB file. I don't know your `data_set`, but I think the `for i in data_set` will always read the next element from `data_set` and make it available as `i`, which you then ignore. That would explain why the 1 line file didn't work. The 10GB file probably also didn't work and is missing all those lines that were wasted as `i`.

Demo:

```
from itertools import islice
it = iter('abcabcabc')
for i in it:
    print(list(islice(it, 2)))
```

Output:

```
['b', 'c']
['b', 'c']
['b', 'c']
```

Comment: When I do something like: `f = open('data1.csv','rb')`, then `r = csv.reader(f)` on a file containing a single row of data, then apply my method or yours to that file I still end up with [ ] as my result.

Comment: A simple example of my data would be something like: 'joe user','2015-05-11T22:10:54','Application Launch Event','X.X.X.X','Application Name','3:57:14'

Comment: What do you mean with my method? I'm just using *yours* to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I figured out the problem is the data being feed to the function.  Passing just a string is fine.  However I am passing tuples which is why I am getting [ ].

Comment: I guess this question can be closed.

Comment: No idea what you're talking about. With "passing just a string is fine", do you mean my demonstration? If so, did you not see that every "a" is missing?